# Limit input length within datefield of Angulars reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Within an Angular Reactive form an input field of type datetime-local is used, which provides following format by default: **dd.mm.yyyy --:--**

Despite this default input format, it is possible to enter the year with up to 6 digits. Is there a possibility to limit the input for the year number to 4 digits?

```
<label for="party">Enter a date and time for your party booking:</label>
<input
  id="party"
  type="datetime-local"
  name="partydate"
  value="2017-06-01T08:30" />
```

I've tried various things with maxlength and pattern attributes, but haven't found a solution. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide a `max` property with some date in the future, provided in the correct format, it works:

```html
<label for="party">Enter a date and time for your party booking:</label>
<input
  id="party"
  type="datetime-local"
  name="partydate"
  value="2017-06-01T08:30"
  max="2200-01-01T00:00"  />
```